# What is the shortest way to update key value when changing sort order

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of objects with a key called order like so:

`[{id:"24fin1st",ruler:false,order:1},
{id:"24fin2nd",ruler:false,order:2},
{id:"24fin3rd",ruler:false,order:3},
{id:"24fin4th",ruler:false,order:4}]`

Let's say we move item four to item two. or item 1 to item 4. What's the most efficient way to update the entire list of key order. I was thinking get the entire array from the origin to the destination and renumber the key in that range something like:

```js
var switchUp = [{
  id: "24fin1st",
  ruler: false,
  order: 1
}, {
  id: "24fin2nd",
  ruler: false,
  order: 2
}, {
  id: "24fin3rd",
  ruler: false,
  order: 3
}, {
  id: "24fin4th",
  ruler: false,
  order: 4
}];

function sortNumber(a, b) {
  return a - b;
}

function resort(org, des, arr) {
  var move;
  if (org > des) {
    move = "up";
    var range = arr.slice(des - 1, org)
  } else {
    move = "down";
    var range = arr.slice(org - 1, des)
  }
  range.forEach(function(su, i) {
    if (su.order === org) {
      su.order = des;
    } else {
      if (move === "up") {
        su.order = su.order + 1;
      } else {
        su.order = su.order - 1
      }
    }

  })
}

resort(1, 3, switchUp);
switchUp.sort(function(a, b) {
  return parseFloat(a.order) - parseFloat(b.order);
});
console.log(switchUp)
```

I think this way is decent, not sure if it's the fastest though.

Comment: If the `order` always corresponds to the position of the object in the array, why have it at all? Why not just use the index? But anyways, if you have less than a couple of thousands elements in the array, I wouldn't worry. I'd just iterate over the whole array.

Comment: If you are doing this often enough to ask for the most efficient way to do it, I would suggest using not an array, but for example a linked list.  And, you can keep an index of only every 5 entries or so.  That way, when you reorder, you don't have to change the index every time.  If you need this explained in more detail, I can post it as an answer.

Comment: @alex never knew of this. But that's what I was looking for(i think). I have never seen one in action do you mind posting how it would work?

Comment: @FelixKling yeah dude I think your right I am thinking of a case maybe 200 tops

Comment: Please do not use the word "efficient" in your questions unless you **really** mean efficient; it is normally interpreted as referring to run-time performance. If you mean "how to", or "best way to", or "shortest way to', then say that. Questions asking about efficiency are prone to being closed as "too broad", since efficiency has many aspects and also depends on the circumstances, the engine, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sort` you apply at the end -- after you have swapped the order value of two nodes -- could take *O(nlogn)* time, while this could be done in *O(n)* with two calls to `splice` and a renumbering loop:

```js
var switchUp = [{
  id: "24fin1st",
  ruler: false,
  order: 1
}, {
  id: "24fin2nd",
  ruler: false,
  order: 2
}, {
  id: "24fin3rd",
  ruler: false,
  order: 3
}, {
  id: "24fin4th",
  ruler: false,
  order: 4
}];

function resort(org, des, arr) {
  var first = Math.min(org, des) - 1,
      last = Math.max(org, des) - 1;
  arr.splice(des-1,0,arr.splice(org-1, 1)[0]);
  for (var i = first; i <= last; i++) {
    arr[i].order = i + 1;
  }
}

resort(3, 1, switchUp);

console.log(switchUp);
```

Note that `splice` will alter the index of all elements following the point of mutation, and this happens again on the second call, which restores the original indexes for elements at the right side of the range that really needs to change. Although `splice` may perform its task very efficiently (as it is an internal method), it might be more efficient (on very large arrays) to shift the elements in range explicitly, one by one:

```js
var switchUp = [{
  id: "24fin1st",
  ruler: false,
  order: 1
}, {
  id: "24fin2nd",
  ruler: false,
  order: 2
}, {
  id: "24fin3rd",
  ruler: false,
  order: 3
}, {
  id: "24fin4th",
  ruler: false,
  order: 4
}];

function resort(org, des, arr) {
  var node = arr[org-1],
      inc = org < des ? 1 : -1;
  for (var i = org-1; i !== des-1; i+=inc) {
       arr[i] = arr[i+inc];
       arr[i].order = i + 1;
  }
  node.order = des;
  arr[des-1] = node;
}

resort(3, 1, switchUp);

console.log(switchUp);
```

On a final note: your function expects indexes that are 1-based, just like the `order` values. But since JavaScript uses 0-based indexing, this can be counter intuitive for someone who uses your code. Where standard array functions like `slice` expect 0-based indexes as arguments, this custom function expects 1-based indexes. It would be a good thing if you would reconsider this choice and work with 0-based indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Just re-assign all the `order` properties:

```
array.forEach((o, i) => o.order = i + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation of a linked list:

```js
    var switchUp = [{
      id: "",
      ruler: false,
      next: "24fin1st",
      prev: "24fin4th"
    }, {
      id: "24fin1st",
      ruler: false,
      next: "24fin2nd",
      prev: ""
    }, {
      id: "24fin2nd",
      ruler: false,
      prev: "24fin1st",
      next: "24fin3rd"
    }, {
      id: "24fin3rd",
      ruler: false,
      prev: "24fin2nd",
      next: "24fin4th"
    }, {
      id: "24fin4th",
      ruler: false,
      prev: "24fin3rd",
      next: ""
    }];

var target="";

function check(val) {
    return val.id == target;
}

//---code to move "24fin1st" before "24fin3rd"---
//first, find the origin and the destination values
target = "24fin1st";
toMove = switchUp.findIndex(check);
target = "24fin3rd";
newNext = switchUp.findIndex(check);

//the inserts switchUp[toMove] before switchUp[newNext]
target = switchUp[newNext].prev;
newPrev = switchUp.findIndex(check);
target = switchUp[toMove].prev;
oldPrev = switchUp.findIndex(check);
target = switchUp[toMove].next;
oldNext = switchUp.findIndex(check);

switchUp[toMove].next = switchUp[newNext].id;
switchUp[toMove].prev = switchUp[newPrev].id;
switchUp[newPrev].next = switchUp[toMove].id;
switchUp[newNext].prev = switchUp[toMove].id;
switchUp[oldPrev].next = switchUp[oldNext].id;
switchUp[oldNext].prev = switchUp[oldPrev].id;

console.log(switchUp);
```

To simplify code, I inserted a "" entry, which points to the first and the last entries.  In general, this is usually managed using code which detects the beginning/ end of an array, and act accordingly.

As you see, the actual index inside the array does not change.  What changes is, the "previous" and "next" pointers.

Now, if you need this array by indices, then you can index every fifth entry, with an index [less than every fifth is not efficient].  It would look something like:

```
var entry = ["24fin1st", "24fin6th", "24fin11th", "24fin16th", "24fin21st"];
var index = [0, 5, 10, 15, 20];
```

If you have moved the 1st entry to the 13th entry, then you would decrease the index by 1 between the 1st and the 13th entry.  So after a super-efficient algorithm checking the values of the index array, the new index array would become:

```
index = [0, 4, 9, 15, 20];
```

Note: a caveat is, if you move an entry in the index (e.g. the 15th entry to the 11th), then you must update the entry array with switchUp[15].next or switchUp[15].prev

Note: if at some point, two adjacent entries of the index array become very far away, then you do have to go through the whole array to re-index the entry and index arrays; however, this should be *very* rare [I can give some probabilities based on how far you index, and how far apart you can accept the bounds to be, and how large your array is].

Finally, if you need to navigate to the, say, 13th entry, then you scan the index array for the closest value (in this case, 15); and then you navigate switchUp.prev two times to get to the 13th entry.

Note: if you store indices instead of labels in the next and prev fields, then this algorithm would be about 20 times more efficient.  In that case, you would replace

```
target = switchUp[toMove].prev;
oldPrev = switchUp.findIndex(check);
```

with

```
oldPrev = switchUp[toMove].prev;
```

We spent an entire week learning about the different types and different functionalities of linked lists, so I can't explain it all in one answer; but if there's something specific you'd like help with, then ask.  I hope you see why I wanted to confirm this is something you would want, before typing it up.